# Report builder 3.0 : Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, web-config

I run a report on the SSRS hosted website on MS2019 server and it works. It is larger than 4MB.

When I download the file, and try to open it after downloading and installing Report Builder 3.0, the following error message appears after trying to run it locally.

> There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config
> file. ---> Maximum request length exceeded.

I cannot seem to locate the web.config file to modify ,as it is not in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRSxx.MSSQLSERVER (where xx is the MS SQL version number) or C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS depending on the SSRS version.

In addition, I tried modifying the config file (web.config.comments) in the following folder with no change: C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_netfx-aspnet_web_config_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_1753fc019a645ad2

Where is the web.config file for Report Builder 3.0?

Answer (score -1):

If you installed Report Builder from the Download Centre site, and accepted the default installation location, then you will find the config file in the folder: C:\Program Files\Power BI Report Builder.

If you installed from the Windows Store, it will be in a different location. You can find the installation location by right-clicking on it's shortcut and choosing "Open file location".

The file you are probably after is not web.config, as this is a windows application. Try PowerBIReportBuilder.exe.config.  That file has a maximumErrorResponseLength property, set to 1024. The comment above it indicates that is in KB

```html
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <!-- increased the maximumErrorResponseLength from 64KB to 1024KB, some SOAP error responses go over the limit -->
      <httpWebRequest maximumErrorResponseLength="1024" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Neither the path nor file exist.

Comment: The question is for Report Builder, not Power BI report builder. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Just right-click the shortcut and choose "Open file location". You usually have to do that twice - the first time from the Start menu takes you to a Windows Explorer folder with shortcut files. Right-click the shortcut file and "Open file location" again to find the install directory.